# How to pass a variable from php code to Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, session-variables

I have an ajax call to some php code that checks for a user's existence, subscriber id and access rights in a custom users table within the Wordpress database. What is the best way to make that subscriber id available to Wordpress pages bearing in mind there could be many subscribers on the system at the same time and each id should be relevant to each user? Outside Wordpress session variables work well but seem to break code within Wordpress. I am using XYZ PHP code for PHP snippets and have Native PHP Sessions for WordPress installed. Whether the latter is active or not seems to make no difference. How should I handle this please?

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be the best way, I have my system working by using cookies.